# Extending the life span of 2FA token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm try to extend the life span of 2FA token to 4 hours instead of the default 15 minutes.

I have tried this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options => options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4));
}
```

but it is not working, it is still defaulting to 15 minutes.

Identity Setup:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(config => {
                config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;

           })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
            .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
            .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
            .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: What are services ? Could you show some more code ?

Comment: @Murat Gündeş https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup#the-configureservices-method

Comment: So, the `ConfigureServices` method should be called by the runtime on startup (doc below). Are you sure it's getting called? Do you hit this breakpoint? Just to rule out a potentially simple issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup#the-configureservices-method

Comment: And can you share the code where you configure auth / asp.net identity?

Comment: Yes, it is getting called.